# Reporting guideline for bayesian using pd and ROPE

Tags: r, bayesian, logistic, reporting, rstan

In the `bayestestR` [articles](https://easystats.github.io/bayestestR/articles/guidelines.html), I came across the reporting guidelines that they recommend

> “the effect of *X* has a probability of ***pd*** of being *negative* (Median = ***median***, 89% CI [ ***HDI_low*** , ***HDI_high*** ] and can be considered as *significant* (***ROPE***% in ROPE).”

Is this applicable for Bayesian logistic regression? Since in logistic regression, we are more interested in the odds ratio.

For instance:
If we are looking at whether vintage transplant (<5 years vs >=5 years) has an association with being vaccine-acceptance.

Based on my results, *“the effect of transplant vintage of >=5 years has a probability of 96.47% of being positive (Median = 2.26, 89% CI [0.25, 4.52] and can be considered as significant (2.45% in ROPE).”*

How do I write it in terms of OR?
*"Patients with transplant vintage of >=5 years have 9.58 times (pd = 96.47%, 2.45% in ROPE) higher odds as compared to those with <5 years."*

Comment: https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpsyg.2019.02767/full describes that ROPE95% can also be applied to logistic models

Comment: @ava I made some updates to my question, perhaps it wasnt clear previously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as you exponentiate the point estimate (the posterior median), you can exponentiate the credible intervals (CIs) to get CIs for odds ratio as well, **but** the CIs must be '[equal tailed intervals](https://easystats.github.io/bayestestR/articles/credible_interval.html)', also called '[central intervals](https://mc-stan.org/rstanarm/reference/posterior_interval.stanreg.html)', rather than 'highest density intervals' - from [here](https://easystats.github.io/bayestestR/articles/credible_interval.html), the important part

> "...the ETI range does not change when transformations are applied to the distribution (for instance, for log-odds to probabilities transformation)..."

Also see [here](https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/exponentiation-or-transformation-of-point-estimates/7848/7). I don't think the *pd* or ROPE reporting would change as they're derived from the model coefficients not odds ratio.

You can get the ETI for the CIs using the `ci()` function with `method="ETI"` from [bayestestR](https://easystats.github.io/bayestestR/reference/ci.html) or `posterior_interval()` from [rstanarm](https://easystats.github.io/bayestestR/reference/ci.html) (I'm sure other packages have the same).

For your example, something like:

*"Patients with transplant vintage of >=5 years have 9.58 times (89% CI [...], pd = 96.47%, 2.45% in ROPE) higher odds as compared to those with <5 years."*

where *89% CI [...]* are the exponential of ETIs (i.e. odds ratio CIs) seems reasonable.