# Exclusion of 0 in 95% Credible Interval

Tags: r, regression, bayesian, logistic

In Bayesian regression, does the exclusion of null value (0 or 1, depending on difference or ratio) in the 95% HDI implies significance (like in frequentist), and what's the relation with ROPE? Is it possible for a null to be excluded but the ROPE to be large? Or for a null to be included but the ROPE to be small?

Ref for ROPE:
https://dominiquemakowski.github.io/publication/makowski2019indices/

Comment: Note that 95% credible intervals are not unique. In a very trivial (and maybe not realistic) example, if you have a parameter that can take values between 0 and 1 and the posterior distribution is completely flat (i.e. uniformly distributed), then you can have $[0, 0.95]$ as a 95% interval, or $[0.05, 1]$. One includes 0 but not 1, one includes 1 but not 0. Which one is significant? That all depends on your point of view and your domain expertise, but in this particular case, both answers are valid simultaneously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In bayesian regression, the marginal posterior distributions are probability distributions of possible regression coefficients. So a marginal posterior distribution for a given IV that does not include 0 in the 95% HDI just shows that 95% of the most likely parameter values based on the data do not include zero. The 'significance' or the importance of that effect depends on the context.

The ROPE is the range of values that would be considered to be *practically* equivalent to no effect. Classic example is an intervention that aims to increase IQ (mean = 100, SD = 15). You might decide that an intervention that changes IQ by 10 points is not important and is therefore practically equivalent to no effect - e.g. if you have posterior mean = 105 and 95% HDI = 103-107 with ROPE = 90-110, then there appears to be an effect (the 'null' is not in HDI), but it is not practically important.

So because the ROPE can be set, it is theoretically possible to have a posterior distribution that doesn't include 0 in 95% HDI but falls within the ROPE (the above example), or for there to be a small ROPE and for 0 to be included in 95% HDI.

Comment: Is it more ideal to use ROPE, to indicate significance?

Comment: Could you look at this question too? In terms of reporting the bayesian stats in papers: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/533014/reporting-guideline-for-bayesian-using-pd-and-rope

Comment: Significance in the sense it is used in frequentist stats (p-values) does not really have an equivalent in bayesian framework. If you're looking for a threshold to determine whether an effect is *practically important* then a ROPE can be used for that. Interpreting the posterior without ROPE can also show the presence and magnitude of an effect. From memory, the paper you linked shows the *probability of direction* actually corresponded most closely with p-values. I used these in a paper (https://doi.org/10.1093/sleep/zsab007) if it's helpful to see an example (not open access unfortunately).